# can't open new activity when click on cardview but It shows toast only

Tags: android, toast, android-cardview

I am using `cardview` for displaying items in gridview. I want to open a new activity but as per my code its shows the toast about the item position. I am not getting where i am making mistake so please help me. Help would be appreciate, thanks in advance.

**DataModel.class**

```
public class DataModel {


    public String text;
    public int drawable;
    public String color;

    public DataModel(String t, int d, String c )
    {
        text=t;
        drawable=d;
        color=c;
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.class**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<DataModel> mValues;
    Context mContext;
    protected ItemListener mListener;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataModel> values, ItemListener itemListener) {

        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        mListener=itemListener;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        DataModel item;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {

            super(v);

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        }

        public void setData(DataModel item) {
            this.item = item;

            textView.setText(item.text);
            imageView.setImageResource(item.drawable);
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(item.color));

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemClick(item);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder Vholder, int position) {
        Vholder.setData(mValues.get(position));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mValues.size();
    }

    public interface ItemListener {
        void onItemClick(DataModel item);
    }

}
```

**MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemListener {


        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add(new DataModel("Item 1", R.drawable.downtoearth, "#FFFFFF"));
            arrayList.add(new DataModel("Item 2", R.drawable.beer, "#3E51B1"));
            arrayList.add(new DataModel("Item 3", R.drawable.ferrari, "#673BB7"));
            arrayList.add(new DataModel("Item 4", R.drawable.jetpack_joyride, "#4BAA50"));
            arrayList.add(new DataModel("Item 5", R.drawable.three_d, "#F94336"));
            arrayList.add(new DataModel("Item 6", R.drawable.terraria, "#0A9B88"));

            RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, arrayList, this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            /**
             AutoFitGridLayoutManager that auto fits the cells by the column width defined.
             **/

            AutoFitGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new AutoFitGridLayoutManager(this, 300);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


            /**
             Simple GridLayoutManager that spans two columns
             **/
            GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DataModel item) {

        //here toast is 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.text + " is clicked", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

after edit i am getting error in the intent.putExtra command

@Override
    public void onItemClick(DataModel item) {

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Yojana.class);
    intent.putExtra("dataitem", item);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Yojana.class

public class Yojana extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yojana);
    getIntent().getParcelableExtra("dataitem");

}
```

logcaterror :

```
    Error:(56, 15) error: no suitable method found for 
    putExtra(String,DataModel)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,boolean) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to boolean)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,byte) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to byte)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,char) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to char)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,short) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to short)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,int) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to int)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,long) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to long)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,float) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to float)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,double) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to double)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,String) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to String)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,CharSequence) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to CharSequence)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,Parcelable) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to Parcelable)
    method Intent.putExtra(String,Parcelable[]) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to Parcelable[])
    method Intent.putExtra(String,Serializable) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to Serializable)
   method Intent.putExtra(String,boolean[]) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to boolean[])
   method Intent.putExtra(String,double[]) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to double[])
   method Intent.putExtra(String,String[]) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to String[])
   method Intent.putExtra(String,CharSequence[]) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to CharSequence[])
   method Intent.putExtra(String,Bundle) is not applicable
   (argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to Bundle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this opens a new activity .but how to open different activities by clicking on different cardviews ?

@Override
    public void onItemClick(DataModel item) {

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Yojana.class);
        intent.putExtra("dataitem", String.valueOf(item));
        startActivity(intent);


}
```

Yojana.class

public class Yojana extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_yojana);
     getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataitem");

}
```

Comment: @ deadpool007  now how to open different activities . how to put conditions on this so that i can open different activity

Answer (score 0):

It shows toast because you have written below code:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.text + " is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Insted you should write below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("dataitem", item);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: . getIntent().getExtras().getString("dataitem");                                             i have written this  in another activity but still i am getting error                                          
   .Error:(56, 15) error: no suitable method found for putExtra(String,DataModel)
method Intent.putExtra(String,boolean) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to boolean)
method Intent.putExtra(String,byte) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; DataModel cannot be converted to byte)

Comment: no make your Dataitem class PARCELABLE that is implement Parcelable interface for your class as you are sending whole object to another activity. and in the NextActivity do this getIntent().getParcelableExtra("dataitem")